# problems uploading data onto QGIS cloud

Tags: qgis-cloud

I am using QGIS 1.8.0 on a windows 7 machine.  Trying to upload a project onto QGIS Cloud.

I have 2 issues. Firstly when i go to publish a map it directs me to upload the data.  As i am using a free account i appear to have the option of 2 databases. fwjdl_kjshzi and eqgmke_bqmbtb.  I don't think i created either database but they are the options.

I go through the process of uploading and when all is uploaded the first problem presents.

I am asked to save the project as a new project. I do so. then it directs me back to uploading again. It is a never ending cycle.  I have the box ticked to replace local data but it seems not to.

Second problem is on some projects which successfully uploaded (some layers did not upload). I would like the layers to be displayed in the groups which i had them in originally. Such as roads in one folder, water data in another, etc.  Is this possible.

I hope this is clear.